# Uncaught Error: Class "Illumninate\Support\Collection" not found

Tags: php, laravel, collections, illuminate

I'm working on a php project and need to use the **Collection** namespace from Illuminate. I have Laravel installed on my computer. However, when I try and create a new collection with:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;


$collection = new Collection();
```

It gives me the error that it cannot find the class `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. I tried moving my Laravel folder into the same directory as the project and that didn't work either. I also tried looking through my laravel folders and couldn't find the Illuminate files anywhere. Do I have to do a separate installation to get the Illuminate libraries? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to include Collection in non laravel project.  If this is the case you could use just the collection package. composer require illuminate/collections

Comment: I had the same issue on a Laravel project. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: It seems PHP version 8.2 have issue with this class,  PHP version 7.4 no problem